Blender 4.1 issues with 3DConnexion SpaceMouse
Blender 4.1 is having a major issue for me. The viewport spirals downward with no touch of buttons.
I have a 3DConnexionn Space Mouse connected but I don't touch anything on it when opening a new file.
I can move the Space Mouse and it registers. The changes it makes aren't enough to fix the view.
Edit: I have tried turning the walk navigation off but that doesn't do a thing. I can use the normal mouse to navigation and freeze the crazy motion but I can't do any functions while holding the normal mouse button in.

Hello, it's not clear what's happening, what does Blender 4.2 or 4.3 give?

Sounds like Walk Navigation is activated with Gravity enabled in the Preferences... without a floor or any object below then you're just falling down endlessly.

Tried that out and it didn't change anything.

This seems to be a known issue in all versions after 3.0.0
https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/107926
Also consider renaming the post to "Blender 4.1 Issue with 3DConnexionn Space Mouse"
